# Is it necessary a "nested" freeing of reserved memory in a std::vector<pair<vector<int>,int>> for manually free it?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have:

```
vector< pair<vector<int> , int> > mapped_samples;
```

This is very large. I would manually free memory. I know that a trick for a simple vector is:

```
vector<int> simple_vector;
vector<int>().swap(simple_vector);
```

In my case it's ok do:

```
vector<pair<vector<int> , int>>().swap(mapped_samples);
```

or is necessary do some nested operation?

(I'm using C++11)

Comment: What makes you think you need to do a nested swap? (the containing vector destroys it's sub vectors on destruction)

Comment: the correct way to "free" a vectors memory is to do nothing

Comment: can you expand on " I would manually free memory.", because I have the feeling that this is where your actual question resides

Comment: @Borgleader I would be sure that not only the elements are destroyed but that the memory is released, for the nested vectors too. There are always pitfalls and I would be sure to make no mistakes

Comment: @Umbert The vector will free the memory on destruction.

Comment: "the correct way to "free" a vectors memory is to do nothing"

I disagree. It frees nothing. I like the swap-to-free.

@Borgleader So you would allocate the vector on the heap if scope lifetime is not desired behaviour? Seems ugly too imho.

Comment: Can you give a clear example of your use case? because honestly I don't know what you're trying to do, or what problem you're trying to solve. Your question implied you needed to manually free the memory from a vector which, in general you don't. Unless you want to keep it under a certain limit within the lifetime of the vector.

Comment: @lars: If it absolutely must be freed before the function scope completes, just put braces around the block of code where you need the `vector` to create a nested scope; declare it after the open brace, and it's guaranteed to be cleaned when you reach the close brace. The `swap` "trick" costs more, initializing and destroying a junk vector (you could just as easily `resize` to avoid the garbage vector). And it's not as flexible; the nested block trick works properly with all RAII resources, even if they don't support `swap`-ing.

Comment: @lars No, doing nothing the system free the memory from yourself. I want free the memory in a definite moment(manually). do simplevector.clear() isn't enough. The mine is correct procedure but I don't know if there is same problem for nested vectors

Comment: @Umbert: The nested `vector`s are destroyed when you `clear`. Technically, the top level `vector` might preserve the space to hold items after a `clear`, but its contents *must* be destructed by the standard. All you're getting, at most, by going any further is recovering the reserved space for the the top-level `vector` (held in case new things are pushed onto it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes you are right, I want be sure that is freed the reserved space that clear does not guarantee and swap yes, but the reserved space for the nested vectors is freed too (or I have to call nested swap)?

Comment: @Umbert vectors release their memory on destruction so no you dont have to nested swap.

Comment: @Umbert: To be clear, the nested vectors are *gone*. The reserved space to accommodate a `vector` is trivial (12-24 bytes IIRC), so unless your top-level `vector` was sized for millions of sub-`vector`s, what's left after clearing it is trivial (and odds are, `vector.clear` will reduce the reserved space if it's too large). All the actual space reserved by those sub-`vector`s for their own items is gone, because they themselves are gone.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm training a neural network. Can reach 1 million and more samples the top-level vector. I also have various structures that handle the same set of samples for various purposes. So releasing the reserved memory space at the top-level  may be  important too. The procedure you mentioned in the answer is ok anyway. Thanks

Comment: Have you look at `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`./

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you absolutely must guarantee that the `vector` is cleaned before the function scope exits, just add additional scope.

For original code:

```
... myfunc(...) {

    ... stuff without vector ...

    vector< pair<vector<int> , int> > mapped_samples;

    ... stuff using vector ...

    ... more stuff without vector ...

}
```

to ensure the `vector` is completely gone after stuff stops using it, just add braces:

```
... myfunc(...) {

    ... stuff without vector ...

    {  // Start of vector's block scope
        vector< pair<vector<int> , int> > mapped_samples;

        ... stuff using vector ...

    }  // End of vector's block scope, guaranteed to be cleaned here

    ... more stuff without vector ...

}
```

This is cleaner than a `swap` trick (which must create and destroy a garbage `vector`), and more general; it works for all RAII resources, and is in fact the common way to use [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're asking is how to reduce the `capacity` of both the outer vector and all nested vectors.

If that is the case, then you'll have to treat each internal vector separately.

For the record, a `swap` probably won't do it since it's most likely implementation will simply swap the 2 vectors' inner implementations.

If I wanted to reduce a vector's capacity I'd probably do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


// general case
template<class Vector>
auto reduce_capacity_impl(Vector& target) -> Vector&
{
    auto temp = Vector();
    temp.reserve(target.size());
    auto first = std::make_move_iterator(target.begin());
    auto last = std::make_move_iterator(target.end());
    std::copy(first, last, std::back_inserter(temp));
    std::swap(temp, target);
    return target;
}

// vector of non-vector
template<class T, class A>
auto reduce_capacity(std::vector<T, A>& target) -> std::vector<T, A>&
{
    return reduce_capacity_impl(target);
};

// vector of vector
template<class T, class AOuter, class AInner>
auto reduce_capacity(std::vector<std::vector<T, AInner>, AOuter>& target) -> std::vector<std::vector<T, AInner>, AOuter>&
{
    for (auto& i : target)
    {
        reduce_capacity(i);
    }

    return reduce_capacity_impl(target);
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> iii;

    reduce_capacity(iii);
}
```

I could be mistaken, and what you want to do is clear the vector and deallocate all memory associated with it.

In this case, swapping with an empty vector will do what you want.